# how to add fancybox when an input submit button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

apparently it seems like this fancybox only works for anchor tags that has an ID or class ?, 
but i want to use it in a submit button...is there a way to use it in that element ?

e.g this doesn't work because fancybox needs an href that will pull the contents

```
<input type="submit" id="submitme" name="submitme" value="SUBMIT ME" />
```

fancy box code

```
$("#submitme").fancybox();
```

Comment: what are you trying/want to display in the fancybox?

Comment: You missed # 
$("#submitme").fancybox(); will work
Please vote up the comment  if its useful thanks

Comment: am gonna display another form ,and this form inside the fancy box, will have a submit button as well, whereby , it will submit the data from it's own input fields and from the parent form data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not whether fancybox can be bound to a `submit` button or not. The actual issue is that your `submit` button doesn't tell fancybox the target content to open and the `type` of content it is.

So having this :

```
<input type="submit" id="submitme" name="submitme" value="SUBMIT ME" />
```

... will work if you hard code the missing elements `href` and `type` in your costom script like :

```
$("#submitme").fancybox({
    type : "iframe",
    href : "http://jsfiddle.net"
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BQ5zc/)**

Optionally, you can hard code any html content too like :

```
$("#submitme").fancybox({
    content : "<p>Any html as content</p>"
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F9m5p/)**

Answer (score 3):

Refer it by #,

```
$("#submitme").fancybox();
```

Comment: doesn't work, either i use an ID nor Class..because it's an input type of element and fancybox needs an <a> tag and an href

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the # in your node reference. But that's probably just because you typed out your code in the question. You could always style a hyperlink to look like a button, give it a URL and attach the fancybox to it:

```
<!--<input type="submit" id="submitme" name="submitme" value="SUBMIT ME" />-->
<a href="somewhere.htm" id="submitme" name="submitme" value="SUBMIT ME" >SUBMIT ME</a>

$("#submitme").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();//stop the hyperlink from navigating away from the current page
}).fancybox();
```

Comment: I haven't shown the CSS mainly because it's not that important. You'll basically want to set border, margin, display:block and background-color if you want your link to look like a button.

Comment: aren't there any other way to use the submit button instead of using that a tag ?

Comment: Yes, but Internet Explorer doesn't play nice when you interrupt the submit button's default behaviour. It's certainly worth a try though. You can use my jQuery code with the button if you like. I'd be interested in the outcome. I'm sorry that I don't have time to investigate.